# Is eating papaya fruit with seeds safe?

Tags: food-safety, seeds, papaya

I once blended whole papaya with seeds to prepare smoothie. After consuming it, I experienced abdominal cramps. I would like to find it if the experience was due to the papaya smoothie I consumed.

Answer (score 3):

Papaya seeds are edible. They are high in insoluble fiber and that can affect digestion, but those health aspects are off-topic for this site.

Comment: If the skin was included; it contains a latex which is irritant. I don't know if it would affect the stomach/intestines, but certainly can irritate the skin. Unripe ones also contain more of this, which can lead to irritation of the intestines apparently. Seeds = fiber = gas...